# how to add domain controller from remote machine in AD

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

In my home i have server 2008 with AD installed.

I have several VM installed using vmware

1stVM = AD DC
2nd VM = RODC

Now in my office i also have many virtual machines.

How can i add one VM in office as Domain controller to my Home computer

All VM have local IP

Comment: That's a bad idea on so many levels.

Comment: I just want to do it for knowledge sake not in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to be connected to your home network from the office using a VPN to actually join this machine to the domain and and promote it to a DC.

After that, this DC will need to regularly replicate to the DC at your home. In a normal set-up, you would have a permanent link between the two and they can replicate as and when they need to. It seems you aren't able to do this, so you are going to need to set-up a replication schedule to allow the DC's to replicate when a VPN link is available.

Have a read of [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755994%28WS.10%29.aspx) to understand AD replication and scheduling better.

Answer (score 0):

The Office AD VM will have to VPN into your home network.

Comment: But  it can't remian in that networkall the time.
How will then big companies do replication on remote computers

Comment: "Big" companies will have dedicated WAN links, or permanent VPN links over the internet or some other permanent network link between the private network's on each site and routing configured so they can communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DCPromo utility to make a server a domain controller using a backup from an existing controller.  Just for testing and development this should be ok.  Check out this document for details:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779518(WS.10).aspx

That covers Server 2003 but 2008 is similar.  Here's the 2008 syntax page:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732887(WS.10).aspx